# Regular expression to parse countries in a string

Tags: regex

My string is like ["AKTIV","sd:RU-HR"] I want to have outputs as RU and HR.
I could reach to result by writing substr and position functions but I am quite sure there is a very straightforward way to achieve it via regexp which I could not manage to do it. TIA.

Comment: In which language/regex engine? Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like JSON, can't you use a JSON parser instead?

Comment: `/(?:(?:sd\:)|(?:\-))([a-zA-Z]+)/g` gets you `RU` and `HR` in pcre and javascript.. but 
as @sp00m said, get yourself a friggin JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to capture hyphen separated alphabets. You can use this regex,

```
([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vecak0/1)**

In case you want lower as well as upper case letters, use this.

```
([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vecak0/2)**